# Fourier transform of convolution of functions in Schwartz Space

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to prove $\widehat{f*g}=\hat f*\hat g$ for $f,g$ in the Schwartz Space, i.e $\sup(|x|^nf^{(k)})<\infty$ for all $n,k$.

$$\widehat{f*g}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-t)g(t)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dtdx.$$ I am trying to apply the interchange of integrals.

So we have:

\begin{align}\widehat{f*g}
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-t)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx g(t)dt
\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx e^{-2\pi it\xi}g(t)dt
\\&=\hat{f}\hat{g}
\end{align}

However, to apply the interchange of integral, I have to make sure $|f(x-t)g(t)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}|=|f(x-t)g(t)|$ is of moderate decrease, i.e $|f(x-t)g(t)|\le\frac{A}{(1+x^2)(1+t^2)}$. I know it is not true that $\exists A>0$ such that $|f(x-t)|\le\frac{A}{1+x^2}$ for all $x,t$. Since here $A$ is independent of $t$, and for each $A$ we can always shift $f$ by $t$ to make some point  of $f(x-t)$ strictly larger than $\frac{A}{1+x^2}$. So we cannot prove $f(x-t),g(t)$ separately. We have to estimate them together to get the decay. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  show that bound, but you do not need to in order to show that the product is integrable.

First the easy way. $|f(x-t)g(t)|\le \|f\|_{L^\infty} \|g\|_{L^\infty} \lesssim 1$, and similarly
$ |(x-t)^2 f(x-t)g(t)| \lesssim 1.$
Together,
$$ |(1+(x-t)^2)f(x-t)g(t)| \lesssim 1$$
and similarly
$$ |(1+(x-t)^2)(1+t^2)f(x-t)g(t)| \lesssim 1$$

Now note
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^2 } \frac1{(1+(x-t)^2)(1+t^2)}dxdt = \int_{\mathbb R^2 } \frac1{(1+y^2)(1+t^2)}dydt < \infty$$
So $f(x-t)g(t)\in L^1(\mathbb R^2)$ and Fubini's theorem applies.

---

If you really want to prove the bound: Note that if $|x-t|\ge |x|/2$, then of course $4(1+(x-t)^2) \ge 1+x^2$. So for such $x,t$,
$$|(1+x^2)(1+t^2)f(x-t)g(t)| \le 4|(1+(x-t)^2)(1+t^2)f(x-t)g(t)|\lesssim 1.$$
But if instead $|x-t|<|x|/2$ then
$$|x|\le |x-t|+|t| < \frac{|x|}2 + |t|$$
so that
$$|x| \le 2|t|.$$
This implies
$$ |(1+x^2)(1+t^2)f(x-t)g(t)| \le 4 |(1+t^2)^2f(x-t)g(t)| \lesssim 1,$$
showing the moderate decrease.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help!

Comment: How to get the last inequality for the case |−|<||/2 ?

Comment: @GordenChan can you write out which ineq?

Comment: @CalvinKhor why the inequality $4|(1+t^2)^2f(x-t)g(t)| \lesssim 1$ holds? here we only have $|(1+(x-t)^2)(1+t^2)f(x-t)g(t)| \lesssim 1$ and $|x-t|<|x|/2$.

Comment: because $f$ is bounded and $g$ is Schwartz? And the inequality before that is using $|x|≤2|t|$ which implies $(1+x^2) ≤ 1+4t^2 ≤ 4(1+t^2)$ @GordenChan

Comment: @CalvinKhor Sorry, I forgot the condition that $f,g$ are in Schwartz space. I am trying to prove that $f(x-t)g(t)$ is of moderate decrease in the condition that $f,g$ are merely of moderate decrease. the first method using Fubini's theorem is still valid, but for your second method,  I can not get the same inequality $4|(1+t^2)^2f(x-t)g(t)| \lesssim 1$.

Comment: I don't think it works for $f,g$ moderate decrease @GordenChan

Comment: @CalvinKhor  Ok, then using Fubini's theorem is better when $f,g$ are of moderate decrease. Thank you for your reply!