# moderately decreasing on $\mathbb R^n$ implies integrable

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

In Stein's Fourier Analysis, he stated

> if $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is moderately decreasing, then $\int_{\mathbb R^n} f<\infty$.

where $f$ is cts and moderately decreasing if $\sup_{\mathbb R^n}|x|^{2}|f(x)|<\infty$ and $\int_{\mathbb R^n} f=\lim_N \int_{Q_N}f(x)=\lim_N\int_{-N}^{N}...\int_{-N}^{N}f(x_1,...,x_n)$.

I am trying to prove this by showing

> $\sup_{\mathbb R^n}(1+x_1^2)(1+x_2^2)...(1+x_n^2)|f(x)|<\infty$ iff $f$ is moderate decreasing.

Since in the previous chapter Stein defined a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is moderate decreasing iff $|f(x,y)|<\frac{A}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}$ for some $A>0$.

The necessary condition is clear as $x_1^2+...+x_n^2\le (1+x_1^2)(1+x_2^2)...(1+x_n^2)$. ButI I have no idea in showing the another side.

Edit: I took the wrong definition of moderate decrease. The definition should be $f$ is cts and moderately decreasing if $\sup_{\mathbb R^n}|x|^{n+1}|f(x)|<\infty$. So my attempt on the necessary condition also does not work.

Comment: You don't need to show that the two supremums are equal (and they don't). You only need to show existence of one of them implies another. Also the dimension $n$ is a constant.

Comment: @Kushi I am not trying to prove the 2 supreme are equal, but proving the finiteness of one of them implies the finiteness of the another.

Comment: Is the definition of moderately decreasing correct? The function $f(x)=\eta(x)|x|^{-2}$ (where $\eta$ is zero in a neighborhood of the origin to cut-off the singularity, but is otherwise just continuous and bounded), then $f$ is moderately decreasing but not integrable on any $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: The definition of moderately decreasing should be changed to $\sup_{\mathbb R^n}|x|^{n+1}|f(x)|<\infty$. Otherwise, this is false.

Comment: @Conifold thank you.  sorry for that, I will edit it.

Comment: @Conifold Could you please give me some hint on this?

Comment: With the fixed growth condition $|f(x)|\leq\frac{M}{|x|^{n+1}}$ and $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$ by continuity, so it is dominated by an integrable function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Regarding the definition of moderate decrease, Stein says in Ch. 6 Section 1.2:

> Two observations are in order. First, we may replace the square $Q_{N}$ by the ball $B_{N}=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}:|x| \leq N\right\}$ without changing the definition. Second, we do not need the full force of rapid decrease to show that the limit exists. In fact it suffices to assume that $f$ is continuous and
> $$
> \sup _{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}}|x|^{d+\epsilon}|f(x)|<\infty \quad \text { for some } \epsilon>0.
> $$
> For example, functions of moderate decrease on $\mathbb{R}$ correspond to $\epsilon=1$. In keeping with this we define functions of moderate decrease on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ as those that are continuous and satisfy the above inequality with $\epsilon=1$.
> The interaction of integration with the three important groups of symmetries is as follows: if $f$ is of moderate decrease, then
> (i) $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(x+h) d x=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(x) d x$ for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$,
> (ii) $\delta^{d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(\delta x) d x=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(x) d x$ for all $\delta>0$,
> (iii) $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(R(x)) d x=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(x) d x$ for every rotation $R$.

2. That said, I did not verify Stein's definition [in an answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4193977/fourier-transform-of-convolution-of-functions-in-schwartz-space), and the reason was that (well, Stein doesn't always clearly mark where the definitions are...but also)  $\frac1{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}$ is indeed integrable on $\mathbb R^2$.  Regardless, the method in that answer  gets you any power, (as the functions there are *rapidly* decreasing) which does finally answer the question with the corrected definition of moderate decrease when you use
   $ (1+x^2+y^2) \le (1+x^2)(1+y^2)$ which gives $(1+|(x,y)|^3) \lesssim (1+x^2)^{3/2}(1+y^2)^{3/2}.$ I will eventually modify the answer there appropriately...
3. For the task at hand, you will want to use polar/spherical coordinates (see the appendix of Stein for a statement of the change of variables theorem,  I believe Rudin has a proof. The radial case has a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389555/integration-of-radial-functions) but using the "coarea formula".) to show that $g(x)=\frac1{1+|x|^{d+1}}$ is integrable. In fact for any $h:\mathbb  R\to\mathbb R$,
   $$\int_{ B_R(0) } h(|x|) dx = \omega_d \int_0^R h(r) r^{d-1} dr$$
   where $\omega_d$ is some constant that depends only on $d$ and not on $h$ or $R$. ($\omega_d$ is the area of the unit sphere of $\mathbb R^d$.)
   Then you can apply some sort of comparison theorem for integrals e.g. [this one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534461/improper-integrals-comparison-theorem)

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your help.